# mount: mydir: cannot mount my.iso read-only

Tags: mount, iso, loop-device

I am trying to mount an ISO file:

```
$ sudo mount isodir/my.iso mydir
mount: mydir: cannot mount isodir/my.iso read-only.
```

Why?

Answer (score 4):

This happens on any FUSE file system, if the file system wasn’t mounted with the `allow_other` option. Attempting to mount a file hosted in a FUSE file system results in `EACCES`, which `mount` misinterprets (in this case) as a failed attempt to mount a read-only file system (which can be indicated by either [`EACCES` or `EROFS`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html#ERRORS)).

This is part of [the restrictions on FUSE](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/fuse.html#how-are-requirements-fulfilled) intended to prevent FUSE being used to gain unauthorised access.

You can work around this, if you trust your FUSE users, by adding the `user_allow_other` option to `/etc/fuse.conf`, and mounting your FUSE file system with `allow_other`.

Comment: Wow, excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the file system of `isodir` is FUSE (`sshfs` for instance), then you will get that error.

Comment: Are you asking yourself for clarifications in an answer?